# aforge camera won't close, error "thread abort is not supported in this platform"

Tags: vb.net, aforge

I am totally new to vb.net and I am trying to incorporate my webcam into the application that i am creating. I have successfully made it run until to the point that i want to close the camera and proceed to other tasks but the camera kept running and when i tried to create a variable that will stop the camera like "camera.stop", i received this error (thread abort is not supported in this platform). i am using vb.net 2019 for this

```
Imports AForge
Imports AForge.Video
Imports AForge.Video.DirectShow
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class CAMERA
    Dim camera As VideoCaptureDevice
    Dim bmp As Bitmap


    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    Private Sub Captured(sender As Object, eventArgs As NewFrameEventArgs)
        bmp = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap)
        PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap)

    End Sub

    Private Sub CAMERA_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load



        Dim cameras As VideoCaptureDeviceForm = New VideoCaptureDeviceForm
        If cameras.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            camera = cameras.VideoDevice
            AddHandler camera.NewFrame, New NewFrameEventHandler(AddressOf Captured)
            camera.Start()

        End If
    End Sub



    Private Sub CAMERA_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

        camera.Stop()

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox4.Click
        Me.Close()

    End Sub


    Private Sub SButton3_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SButton3.Click
        PictureBox2.Image = PictureBox1.Image
    End Sub

    Private Sub SButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SButton1.Click

        If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

            PictureBox2.Image.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End If
        MessageBox.Show("PROFILE IMAGE UPDATED")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need this but as I had the same problem I thought it might be useful to post the answer for the next person.
According to Aforge:
VideoCaptureDevice stop is now obsolete and you need to use SignalToStop.

If you need to wait for it to stop there is the WaitForStop method.
More info at:
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/c467086b-99dc-b7b8-cc45-f43247c2674c.htm